# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE in spooled log file?

Tags: oracle, package, sqlplus

I have created package like this:

```
create or replace package test_package is
    procedure ShowDate;
end test_package;
/
create or replace package body test_package is
  PROCEDURE ShowDate
  IS
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
  END ShowDate;

end test_package;
/
```

I'd like to run this package using sqlplus and have result (SYSTDATE) stored in a log file.

I've created a file ShowDate.sql containing:

```
call test_package.showdate()
```

I've tried ro run in as:

```
sqlplus user/password@server 
spool ShowDate.log 
@ShwoDate.sql 
spool out.
```

But the onlu result I can see is: `Call completed.`

I have also tried modification of ShowDate.sql :

```
begin
test_package.showdate;
end;
/
```

but then I get `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Can anyone help?

Regards

Pawel

Answer (score 1):

You need this line in your SQL*Plus script (before the procedure call):

```
set serveroutput on
```

Comment: I knew it must be some setting. Thanks!